# navigate from lwc to visualforce that depends on controller state

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, navigation

I'm migrating a visualforce that lets you search and print checks, to LWC. So this visualforce used this other one with renderAs=pdf for the printing part:

```
<body>
    <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!1}"/>
    <apex:variable var="cssValue" value=""/>
    
    <apex:repeat value="{!cheques}" var="w">
        <apex:variable var="cssValue" value="{!IF(counter == 1, '', 'page-break-before: always;')}" rendered="{!counter == 1}" />
        <apex:variable var="hojaA4" value="{!counter == IF(formato == 'PATAGONIA', 4, 5) && imprimirPlancha}"/>
        <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!1}" rendered="{!counter == IF(formato == 'PATAGONIA', 4, 5) && imprimirPlancha}" />
        <apex:variable var="cssValue" value="{!IF(hojaA4, 'page-break-before: always;', '')}" rendered="{!!hojaA4 && imprimirPlancha}" />

        <div style="width: 100%; padding: 0mm; margin: 0mm;{!cssValue}">
          <c:printChequeCMP chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == null}"/>
          <c:printChequeBancor chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'BANCOR'}"/>
          <c:printChequePatagonia chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'PATAGONIA'}"/>
          <c:printChequeSantander chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'SANTANDER'}"/>
          <c:printChequeGalicia chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'GALICIA'}"/>
          <c:printChequePampa chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'PAMPA'}"/>
          <c:printChequeNacion chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'NACION'}"/>
          <c:printChequeCredicoop chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'CREDICOOP'}"/>
          <c:printChequeMacro chqId="{!w.cheque.Id}" rendered="{!formato == 'MACRO'}"/>
        </div>
        <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!counter+1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>

</body>
```

As you see, it renders one of all those components depending on the value of the "formato" property of the controller its associated to (the same controller associated to the main vf).

My approach is to navigate to this same vf from my new LWC. My question is, how do I change this so it doesn't depend on the controller? I want to pass the format value from my LWC directly.

Comment: You can update the controller to receive and initialize "formato" as a page parameter during controller construction (and if the value isn't available fall back to existing behaviour) and have the LWC pass the required value. If using the NavigationMixin, you can include the query parameter directly in the URL or you can include one called "c__formato" in the state; your choice.

Comment: thanks. I'll try this, I wanted to know if I could leave the old controller as it was and try to solve it without it, but I guess it is the most simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the controller to receive and initialize "formato" as a page parameter during controller construction (and if the value isn't available fall back to existing behaviour) and have the LWC pass the required value in the URL.

If using the [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) in your LWC to generate that URL, you can either include the query parameter directly in the URL or you can include one called "c__formato" in the state; your choice. If you use the latter approach your Visualforce page will have to look for this prefixed name, not just "formato".